# Batch / cmd for loop syntax mistake

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, netsh

This is not the full scope of what I'm doing.  I've distilled down...
I'm sure there is something tiny and stupid I'm failing to account for here, I just don't see it.

Can someone please tell me why I can execute the following `netsh` command successfully:

```
netsh wlan show profile name="SomeWifi"
```

Yet, it fails in a for loop?

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %a in ('netsh wlan show profile name="SomeWifi"') do echo %a
```

Instead of the profile info, in the for loop it spits out this error message:

> There is no such wireless interface on the system.

What am I missing? Is the context changed in the parenthesis (like the user)?  Is there a character escape issue?

Comment: `=` is handled as a delimiter and discarded. Escape it using `name^="SomeWifi"`

Comment: That's it! Awesome.  Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some characters that need to be escaped (using `^` as a prefix) when directly used in a `for /f` command.

Some of them are the usual `&` and `|` that having a special meaning to the parser seem that *obviously* need scaping. Another problematic character is the closing parenthesis (`)`) that can be seen as the closing parenthesis of the `in` clause of the `for` command.

But some characters (ex. `,`, `;`) need escaping just because they are seen as delimiters and removed. In your case `=` generates the problem

You can use

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %a in ('netsh wlan show profile name^="SomeWifi"') do echo %a
```